# How to stretch one object along multiple curves

Tags: bezier-curves, hair

How to stretch one object along multiple curves at once?

I want to make hair cards. If I extrude the curves using geometry tab and then convert the curves to objects, I get hair cards and can unwrap them. However, I will lose the ability to edit them using bezier curves (I can just move the vertices).

I have a tape with UV, and I want to stretch it along all the curves at once (without creating a million copies of the tape and applying modifiers to each tape for a each curve). How to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "hair cards" and "tape"?

Comment: you can create linked-duplications of your mesh, so that if you change one of its instance, it will change all the others

Comment: Create your object as a curve and use it as the "bevel curve" of the other object.